# Perl Uninitialized Value Hash Lookup Gene Symbol

Tags: regex, perl, hash, initialization

Update (2):

Changed the code to discard comments in header but still run into a syntax in the hash key/value assignment:

syntax error at ./convertDataToGeneSymbol.pl line 99, near "$geneSymbolToGo{"
syntax error at ./convertDataToGeneSymbol.pl line 101, near "}"

I can't seem to find any mistakes in the code, so I am thinking that the array is failing to read a value for $go maybe?

Here is a header for the input file 3:

!10-20 lines of comments

UniProtK /t BA0A021WW37   /t   CG17167    /t     GO:0016021   /t   GO_REF:0000038
(Still learning how to format on this site; /t means tab seperation)

P.S. Sorry about the comments. My professor requires extensive commenting for our programs. Strict has been giving me some issues with regards to this program (mainly due to my inexperience) but when I remove it I have been getting the results I want. Thank you for all the help so far by the way!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

# Title: convertDataToGeneSymbol.pl
# Author: Nicholas Bense
# Date: 11/4/15

# Open a filehandle to read file #1
open(INF1,"<",'/scratch/Drosophila/fb_synonym_fb_2014_05.tsv' ) or die $!;

# Open a filehandle to read file #2
open(INF2,"<",'/scratch/Drosophila/FlyRNAi_data_baseline_vs_EGF.txt') or die $!;

# Open a filehandle to read file #3
open(INF3,"<",'/scratch/Drosophila/gene_association.goa_fly') or die $!;

# Open a filehandle to write new file
open(OUTF1,">",'FlyRNAi_data_baseline_vs_EGFSymbol.txt') or die $!;

# Open a filehandle to write new file
open(OUTF2,">",'FlyRNAi_data_baseline_vs_EGF_GO.txt') or die $!;

# Initialize a hash for the gene symbol conversion
my %geneSymbolConversion;

# Read input file 1 line by line
while (<INF1>){

# Get rid of whitespace
        chomp;

# Split the line
        my @inf1Array = split("\t", $_);

# Filter entries starting with FBgn
        if ($inf1Array[0] =~ /(^FBgn\d+)/){

# Assign column 1 to hash key scalar
        my $geneID = $inf1Array[0];

# Assign column 2 to hash value scalar
        my $geneSymbol = $inf1Array[1];

# Assign key and value to hash
        $geneSymbolConversion{$geneID} = $geneSymbol;

}

}

# Discard first line of input file 2
<INF2>;

# Read input file 2 line by line
while (<INF2>){


        # Get rid of whitespace
        chomp;

        # Split the line on tabs
        my ($geneID, $egf_Baseline, $egf_Stimulus) = split("\t", $_);

        # Check if the codon is present in the hash
        if (defined $geneSymbolConversion{$geneID}){

                # Get the value associated with the codon from the hash
                $geneSymbol = $geneSymbolConversion{$geneID};
        }

        # Join data and print to output file
        print OUTF1 join( "\t", $geneSymbol, $egf_Baseline, $egf_Stimulus), "\n";
}

# Initialize hash for GO conversion
my %geneSymbolToGo;

<INF3>;

# Read input file 3 line by line
while (<INF3>){

        # Get rid of whitespace
        chomp;

        # Discard comment lines
        if ($_ !~ /!/){

        # Split the line on tabs
        my @inf3Array = split("\t", $_);

        # Assign column 3 to hash key scalar
        my $geneSymbol = $inf3Array[2];

        # Assign column 4 to hash value scalar
        my $go = $inf3Array[3];

        # Assign key and value to hash
        my $geneSymbolToGo{$geneSymbol} = $go;
        }
}

# Open a filehandle to read file #3
open(INF4,"<",'FLYRNAi_data_baseline_vs_EGFSymbol.txt') or die $!;

# Read input file 4 line by line
while (<INF4>){

        # Remove end of line characters
        chomp;

        # Split the line on tabs
        my ($geneSymbol, $egf_Baseline, $egf_Stimulus), "\n";

        # Check if the gene symbol is present in the hash
        if (defined $geneSymbolToGo{$geneSymbol}){

                # Get the value associated with the codon from the hash
                $go = $geneSymbolToGo{$geneSymbol};

        }

        # Join data and print to output file
        print OUTF2 join( "\t", $go, $egf_Baseline, $egf_Stimulus), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Please also include samples of the inputs so we can replicate the problem.

Comment: [Crossposted](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1147001) to PerlMonks.

Comment: Line 34 appears to be an infinite loop.

Comment: Why do you have `use diagnostics` but not `use strict`? The diagnostics will slow down stuff a lot and are not helping with your problem.

Comment: suggestions: fix your indentation, [use autodie](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) and use [lexical filehandles](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::InputOutput::ProhibitBarewordFileHandles)

Comment: Please *always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the start of *every* Perl program you write, especially before asking for help with it. `warnings` and `diagnostics` are far less useful without `strict`

Comment: You have *way* too many comments. I understand needing to comment more when you're unfamiliar with a language, but not on *every damn line* and not in terms that just replicates what the line of code says

Answer (score 1):

- *Always*

  ```
  use strict;
  use warnings 'all';
  ```

  at the start of *every* Perl program. `use diagnostics` is less useful unless you are having trouble understanding the error messages that are produced by these two
- If you have many disk operations to perform then `use autodie` is useful to avoid having to write sensible code to catch any errors, like `or die $!`, after each operation
- *Always* use lexical file handles. For instance

  ```
  open my $inf1_fh, '<', '/scratch/Drosophila/fb_synonym_fb_2014_05.tsv'
  ```

  and name them better. Your code goes to two extremes, and uses overly wordy `geneSymbolConversion` for basic data, but `INF1`, `INF2` etc. for file handles. I don't understand your application, but I'm sure it's not hard to think of something that reflects the file's purpose and add a `_fh` to say that it's a file handle
- It can cause problems if you use identifiers that begin with a capital letter for your local variables. People who are familiar with Perl would also thank you for avoiding capital letters *anywhere* in the name, and using *snake case*, so `%geneSymbolConversion` is better written as `%gene_symbol_conversion`

  Your identifiers are also way too long. We can abbreviate this hash's name further to `%conversion` without ambiguity
- The first parameter to `split` is a *regular expression*, and the default for the second parameter is `$_`, so it is best to write

  ```
  split("\t", $_)
  ```

  as

  ```
  split /\t/
  ```
- Your regex `/(^FBgn\d+)/` captures the matched string, but the capture is never used so you should write just `/^FBgn\d+/`
- I don't understand what you're doing with your `while` loop

  ```
  while ( $INF1Array[0] =~ /(^FBgn\d+)/ ) { ... }
  ```

  because `$INF1Array[0]` (which should be `$inf1_array[0]`) is never changed in the body of the loop, so it will never terminate. My guess is that the `while` should be an `if`
- Make use of Perl's *defined or* operator. Instead of

  ```
  my $geneSymbol = "NA";

  if ( defined $geneSymbolConversion{$geneID} ) {
      $geneSymbol = $geneSymbolConversion{$geneID};
  }
  ```

  you should have

  ```
  my $gene_symbol = $conversion{$gene_id} // 'NA'
  ```

Here's my stab at writing something more Perlish and usable. It's far from being a complicated program, so I don't think it needs any comments at all. The vertical space they take up is much more of an obstacle to clarity than they make up for in their explanations

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;

my %conversion;

{
    open my $in_fh,  '<', '/scratch/Drosophila/fb_synonym_fb_2014_05.tsv';

    while ( <$in_fh> ) {
        chomp;

        my ($gene_id, $gene_symbol) = split /\t/;
        $conversion{$gene_id} = $gene_symbol if $gene_id =~ /^FBgn\d+/;
    }
}

{
    open my $in_fh,  '<', '/scratch/Drosophila/FlyRNAi_data_baseline_vs_EGF.txt';
    open my $out_fh, '>', 'FLYRNAi_data_baseline_vs_EGFSymbol.txt';

    while ( <$in_fh> ) {
        chomp;

        my ( $gene_id, $egf_baseline, $egf_stimulus ) = split /\t/;

        my $gene_symbol = $conversion{$gene_id} // 'NA';

        print $out_fh join("\t", $gene_id, $gene_symbol, $egf_baseline, $egf_stimulus), "\n";
    }
}
```